# LinkedIn oauth v1 login - scope rw_migration error

Tags: oauth

> Scope "rw_migration" is not authorized for your application
>   What does this error means? I cannot find any info "rw_migration scope" over all internet.

I received it when calling api:
https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=77--431b154d-b301-49c8-8822-69dedb96fa8a

I'm using Drupal 7 and oauthconnector module if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is this:

> Update: As of May 1, 2019, Version 1.0 of our API is no longer
>   supported. Applications requesting Version 1.0 APIs may experience
>   issues as we begin to remove services. To find the latest updates, go
>   to the new LinkedIn Developers site at
>   https://www.linkedin.com/developers/. You can learn more about our
>   Version 2.0 APIs, our developer program, and how to migrate your apps.

and

> Authentication: We will sunset OAuth 1.0 and require all developers to
>   use OAuth 2.0, which we have supported since 2013. OAuth 2.0 is the
>   industry standard and widely-used by the majority of people building
>   on our platform.

and

> To reiterate: all developers need to migrate their apps to our newest APIs and OAuth 2.0 by May 1, 2019.

https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates